# How can I move this structure up one block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to be able to move this structure (see first image) up or down one block. For up, I have this:

/clone ~-1 ~-2 ~-3 ~5 ~6 ~19 ~-1 ~ ~-3 replace force

In the indicated command block. However, when the command block executes the command, this:
[image]
goes to this:
[image]
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct (have you intentionally activated it multiple times? If not, that may be a problem with your setup), you should be able to change the `[cloneMode]` mode to `move` rather than `force`.

```
/clone ~-1 ~-2 ~-3 ~5 ~6 ~19 ~-1 ~ ~-3 replace move
```

The coordinates you have given move it up two blocks, (from `y=~-2` to `y=~`). If you only want it to move up one block, try changing the coordinates like this:

```
/clone ~-1 ~-2 ~-3 ~5 ~6 ~19 ~-1 ~-1 ~-3 replace move
```